# What could be the reason for frequently losing the internet connection?

Tags: performance, internet-connection, ping, modem, dsl-modem

I am frequently losing access to internet. Nearly 3 out of 10 pages I open in browser wont open, as if I'm not connected to internet at all. I tested my *wireless* connection using `ping -t` and here is the result:

[image]

I tried connecting to my modem using Ethernet cable, but the connection quality was almost the same. I thought maybe the modem splitter was malfunctioning, and plugged out the phone, but again got no positive result. What could be the problem? Is there anything else I can do before contacting my ISP? Is there anything in the modem settings I can change?

Comment: Did you have a look at your router's logs? If you have the same issue both in wired and wireless environments, I'd discard anything in your home configuration and would rather look for an issue somewhere between your router and the ISP.

Comment: @nKn I just looked at it. Nothing remarkable there.

Comment: Then I'd bet the problem is definitely where I told you, I think contacting your ISP is unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing you could definitely try before contacting your ISP.
Power down your modem for a minute! Literally unplug it!

Beware, most modems will remember the settings they had and automatically reconnect, but some may actually need reconfiguring after you unplugged them.

It might be the most obvious thing to do, but sometimes it is enough to resolve a random glitch. Your ISP would most likely ask you to give it a try as well.